# No method is configured to handle the multipart config key - Laravel 5.4 using mailgun

Tags: php, guzzle, mailgun, laravel-5.4

I’m trying to send emails but is errors appears:

**InvalidArgumentException in MessageFactory.php line 185:**

**No method is configured to handle the multipart config key**

I’m working width laravel 5.4, mailgun driver, and "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~4.0”. 
I have this code on the controller:

```
return Mail::send('emails.message', $data, function($message) use ($request)
{
           $message->from(env('CONTACT_MAIL'), env('CONTACT_NAME'));

           $message->subject($request->subject);

           $message->to(env('CONTACT_MAIL'), env('CONTACT_NAME'));

       });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.2"`. Guzzle 4 is outdated.